# Is it possible to send mdadm alerts using s-nail instead of postfix?

Tags: linux, email, mdadm

I run a mailcow server. I am able to send mail using s-nail from the terminal. I'd like to tell mdadm to just use that when sending email alerts, but when I run `mdadm --monitor --scan --test -1`, it gives me this.

```
sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
```

It seems silly to install postfix just for this. If I do, I'll need to make sure it doesn't interfere with mailcow's postfix, right? Anyway, I'd love some opinions. What's the best course of action?

Comment: To me it looks like this is a sendmail issue, not an mdadm issue.

Comment: Yes, I don't use sendmail for anything, I use s-nail. Was hoping I could get mdadm to do so as well before I dive into installing more software and combing through more config files.

Comment: mdadm is calling a binary called `sendmail`. This binary can be provided by various packages. Check which package it belongs (how to do that depends on your distribution, google it) to and configure it properly.